# Autre nom que "caban" pour un "pea coat"

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, québec, habillement

Lorsque le [caban](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caban) est devenu à la mode il y a quelques années, j'en ai cherché dans des boutiques à Québec, avec autant les mots "caban" que "pea coat". Je suis peut-être mal tombé, mais personne ne semblait connaître.... Même si c'était un style populaire.

Alors, comment appelle-t-on ça, en français parlé au Québec, un "pea coat"?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais su comment ce style de manteau s'appelait, je l'ai toujours appelé « un genre de trench coat », faute de quelque chose de mieux.

Comment: J'ai jamais entendu ce mot. Les synonymes sont « veste » et « manteau »...

Comment: @AlexisWilke "Veste" et "manteau" sont beaucoup plus génériques.

Comment: Oui, mais comme tu le dis toi-même, personne ne connait ce mot...

Answer (score 3):

Comme [Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pea-jacket?q=peacoat) réfère pour *pea coat/pea jacket* à :

> a short double-breasted overcoat of coarse woollen cloth, formerly worn by sailors.

Donc on peut s'attarder en termes d'usage au sens du *overcoat* et c'est l'idée, plus [générique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manteau_%28v%C3%AAtement%29), de [*pardessus*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pardessus) et donc « pardessus imperméable » ou « pardessus pour la mer » devrait être compris.

Comment: Si tu me parles de _pardessus pour la mer_, je pense au [ciré](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cir%C3%A9) bien avant le [caban](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caban). Pardessus, même qualifié d'imperméable, recouvre beaucoup plus que _caban_ hors la question était de voir s'il y avait un autre nom plus répandu désignant explicitement le caban.

Comment: @Unfrancophone En effet, pardessus est plus générique, au même titre que caban est trop spécifique en ce qui a trait à l'usage à Québec. Personellement je n'avais jamais entendu ce mot avant de venir ici. En ce sens ma réponse ne répond pas à la question mais offre une alternative qui permettra, je l'espère, à l'auteur de trouver son caban en magasin!

Answer (score 1):

Le mot "parka", très utilisé en France, et connu depuis le XVIIIème siècle, est d'origine aléoute.

Comment: Mais à regarder ce qu'on trouve avec une recherche de [parka](https://www.google.ca/search?q=parka&safe=off&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=zvhNUp7OH4rS9gS0zIH4Cg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=979&dpr=1), on voit qu'il y a plusieurs modèles, mais bien peu de pea coat.

Comment: Oui, mais une parka et un caban, ce n'est pas la même chose.

Comment: Mais... mais, parka est masculin ici! (Je viens d'apprendre ça)

Comment: "Vareuse" alors ?

Comment: _Vareuse_ me semble mal convenir.  J'ai en tête quelque chose qui n'a qu'une rangée de boutons, un col bien plus ouvert et j'imagine facilement porter un caban par dessus une vareuse.

Answer (score 1):

Mon vieil Harrap's compact traduit :

> **caban** : *nm nau[tical]* (terme de marine) : *peajacket*, *reefer (jacket)*.

Vous aurez peut-être plus de chance de dégoter un *caban* dans les villes où la pêche côtière est active, où les traditions marines (voile en particulier) perdurent.